# Is the number 8 special in turning a sphere inside out?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, differential-topology

So after watching the famous video on youtube *How to turn a sphere inside out* I noticed that the sphere is deformed into 8 bulges in the process. Is there something special about the number 8 here? Could this be done with any number of bulges, including 2?

Image:

[image]

Video: [How to Turn a Sphere Inside Out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_w4HYXuo9M)

Comment: I don't understand in this matter much, but as far as I know, the process would be much faster using 8 bulges rather than 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, 8 isn't special beyond it being the choice they made for that specific video.

The software the group wrote to make that video allowed you to choose that parameter arbitrarily.  I bet if you spent some time digging you could find that software somewhere on the internet, and create your own eversion videos with a different choice of the number of corrugations.

You can find a (modified) version of the source code here: http://profs.etsmtl.ca/mmcguffin/eversion/

as well as commentary from Silvio Levy on the choice of number of strips.

Comment: So if I'm interpreting this correctly, it's an open question? There could exist eversions with fewer bulges but no one is sure?

Comment: Such eversions exist but whether or not the software actually produces them is not known.  If you think through the argument Thurston gives in the outside-in video, it works with any number of corrugations.  But the software has limitations so what it does exactly if you specify only two, I don't know.  I think I used to know but I've forgotten!